# Joomla Permissions

Tags: permissions, joomla1.5

I am new to Joomla and have been given the task of supporting a site that was created in Joomla 1.5.25. They keep getting errors that files are not writable. They also can't add or delete anything to and from the media manager even in a Super Administrator account. I was able to override these errors with changing folder permissions from 755 (Joomla's recommended permission set) to 777, but was wondering if there is a better way of going about this (I don't want to leave a security hole on their site with the 777 permission set). From what I have read through my research is Joomla permissions requirements can vary based on your hosting company, so I want to get other peoples input before I give my hosting company a call.

On a side note, is there a way of getting the error messages to display longer then 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try changing the permissions only to the folders that are written to temporarily? Another solution is to find out under which user apache is running and make sure that user is the owner or at least in a group that owns your Joomla! directory.

Comment: This is where it gets tricky. The Joomla install was migrated over from another hosting company and does not have its own directory. All Joomla related directory's, and files are located right inside the httpdocs folder, along with a Magento install and every-other HTML/CSS/JS file that has nothing to do with Joomla. I'm pretty sure it wasn't migrated properly. I have been changing the permissions temporary, but I keep getting emails from them with another file that is un-writable. Maybe I'll look into migrating their CMS to WordPress. Do you know of any Joomla to WordPress migration tools?

Comment: @JonathanMoriarty Idk of any tools. Sorry. Why not just download joomla again and separate it into a new folder. Then point that working install to the working database.

Comment: I assume I will have to install all of the module/plugins again after this. Does the database store the module/plugin settings at least?

Comment: @JonathanMoriarty It depends on how the module and plugins were designed. It's hard to say. You might be able to copy the modules and plugin folders over.